# Ajax Json While Loop

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

Hi i im trying to get a value from a database and display it as a link in my navigation bar but i haven't been very successfull.

Start Off with my JQuery

```
 <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
              $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {loadpage: 'table'},
                    url: 'addtable.php',
                    success: function(data){    

                        $('.navbar ul').append('<li><a href="#" class="table">'+THE-PHP-ARRAY I WANT TO SHOW+'</a></li>');
                    } 
                }); //ajax request
             });
    </script>
```

addtable.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Menus WHERE menuCreator = '".$_SESSION['U_ID']."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$index=0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

    $index++;
    $data = array(

        $index=>$row['menuName']
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

I tried alot of stuff. If i change my dataType to json it doesnt work at all. I tried to put it in an $.each() loop still nothing works. If i go to addtable.php it displays

{"1":"Breakfast"}{"2":"Book Fair"}

which is the correct values in my database

Im sorry if it wasn't too clear im 15 and i only do this between school any help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode` outputs a complete JSON text, but outputting it inside a loop you are outputting a bunch of JSON texts butting up against each other. The result isn't a valid, single JSON text.

Put `$data` into an array.

Encode that array as JSON **after** the loop has finished.

Then you'll need to loop over that array (`data`) when it gets converted to JavaScript.

Comment: how can i loop data in javascript $.each()?

Comment: The function is documented — http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ — what don't you understand? (That should probably be a new question and not a comment though).

Comment: no i meant should i use the each function i wasn't asking for what it did sorry for the miscommunication. I just want to clarify something else, so should i put the variable $data which contains an array and then put it into another array and json encode it?

Comment: Before the loop: Create an array. In the loop: Put $data (an *associative* array) into that array. After the loop: JSON Encode the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"1":"Breakfast"}{"2":"Book Fair"}
```

is not a valid JSON object. if you want to encode multiple objects, you need to do it like this:

```
[{"1":"Breakfast"}, {"2":"Book Fair"}]
```

or if you just need the values:

```
["Breakfast", "Book Fair"]
```

For loading it from the server you should use the shorthand function [jquery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)